# Firebase initialization problem in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use Firebase in an app component. This is how the code looks like for that component (removed the api details from json while posting here).

```
import React from "react";
import * as firebase from "firebase";

const New_meet =() =>{
    
    var firebaseConfig={
        apiKey: ,
        authDomain: ,
        databaseURL: ,
        projectId: ,
        storageBucket: ,
        messagingSenderId: ,
        appId: ,
        measurementId: 
    };
    
    console.log("here");
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    
    const preObject = document.getElementById('object');
    const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('object');
    dbRefObject.on('value',snap=>console.log(snap.val()));
    
    return(
        <div>
            <p id="object"></p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default New_meet;
```

The problem is, when I insert that firebaseInitializeApp function(already present for now), it gives the error

```
"Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)."
```

And when I remove that line, it shows

```
 "Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)"
```

I am not importing firebase in App.js or any other components. Have never used Firebase before so no clue how to tackle this.

Comment: try moving your firebaseConfig and initializeApp method outside/before the component

Comment: On every update, it's going to initialize, the firebase, but you have to do that only once, don't know the structure, but just like redux store we initialize that once, you have to do prevent that re-initialization.

Comment: @VaibhavRai Any ideas on how it's done? I have never used firebase before, and can only find android solutions online, not javascript.

Comment: @wdm that worked! although snap updates are not happening, but maybe that error is in my code. I will figure that out.Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @titichh51477 like Prateek answered you should create a global object or use react context and pass it further.

Comment: @VaibhavRai yeah that works, along with moving the config json and initialize method  outside the component, as mentioned by wdm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're using a new instance of the firebase app every time the module reloads.

You have to initialize your firebase once and use the instance throughout your app.

Create a new file where you could initialize firebase and use it throughout the app.

`firebase.js`

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

try {
   firebase.initializeConfig({ /* Config here* /})
} catch(err) {
   // swallow the error
   console.log(err)
}

/* use this firebase in your project. */
export default firebase;
```